# Is David Cross playing the same character in both MIB and MIB2?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-2

IMDB lists David Cross' character in MIB as an unnamed "[morgue attendant](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0432066/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t25)" and as "[Newton](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0002784/?ref_=tt_cl_t10)" in MIB2, however the [MIB Wikia](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Newton) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black_(film_series)) both state unequivocally that they're the **same person**:

> Newton is a recurring minor character in the Men in Black films.
>   Newton originally worked at a morgue with Laurel. He is portrayed by
>   David Cross.

---

**Is there any out-of-universe confirmation (e.g. from interviews, etc) that he's playing the *same* character or is this simply an error on the wikia/s?**

[image]

Comment: In-universe, according to [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Men-in-Black.html), Cross' MiB character has a different name (Tony; although I suppose it's not impossible his name is Tony Newton), and he dies. It does seem unlikely that they're the same character

Comment: @JasonBaker - The script you're referring to is a pre-production draft which means that it's not quite the same as the film. Interestingly, the novelisation appears to be based on that script since it also mentions his name as Tony. Unfortunately, neither of these necessarily answer the question since, at least theoretically he might have survived.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto - That's my impression too, but I'm not ready to write off the wiki until I see some concrete proof in the form of an interview or something.

Comment: I was genuinely confused by his reappearance; given how The Bug rolled in MiB, it was natural to assume the morgue attendant was dead.

Comment: I was watching MIB 1 and 2 last weekend and had the same thought occur to me!  Looking forward to the answer

Comment: @Richard I do think that was a waste of rep though.

Comment: @bleh - 500 rep is not a lot.

Comment: @Richard For me it is.

Comment: @bleh - Economy of scale. That's like 2 days worth for me.

Comment: The credits for MIB list David Cross as "Morgue Attendant".

Comment: @Richard At this month's rates, you will *never* catch DVK ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - sure he will. I'll be off vacation (and everyone will be off "The Plot Holes Awaken" bandwagon) in a few days.

Comment: @Randal'thor - Marathon, not a sprint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

[Tastes like Chicken's: "DAVID CROSS interview by darby o'gill"](http://web.archive.org/web/20030629110542/http://www.tlchicken.com/view_story.php?ARTid=635) has this Q&A with him:

> **d:** *I also noticed that you're going to be in Men In Black 2 this summer. Please don't take this the wrong way, but **didn't you die in the first Men In Black**?*
>
> **D:** *YEAH! That was ####ng’ weird! The director really liked me, and he wanted me to be in this movie. Just like the first one, it was another small part. We were on the set shooting the first scene. I think we had shot it twice, when he came over in the middle of shooting, and he says, "**What if you're the same guy, from the last movie**?" I was like, “How would that work?” He just wrote some lines down, and says, "**Say this, 'You don't remember me? I was the guy you slimed**.'" **And that was that**.*

Now, this is **somewhat suspicious**, because that phrase **does not appear in the film**. But there you have it, a claim from the man himself that it was the same character.

Comment: Boom. Headshot.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the MiB1 and MiB2 novels are conflicted on the issue;

> ***A dead man was stuck to the high ceiling** by a wad of viscous, dripping goo. The guy had a can of Raid in one hand and a really surprised expression on his face.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black: A novelisation](http://MiB1:%20A%20novel)</sup></sub>

Versus

> *"You don't remember me," Newton went on. "Nineteen ninety-seven? The morgue? **I was the guy slimed on the ceiling?"**  To blank stares, Newton continued "The tape you reserved....*
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black 2: Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2551658.Men_in_Black_II)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after he was stuck on the ceiling at the morgue he was neuralyzed and given a new job as a video store worker? That's the best I can guess.

It would be nice if the Director or Writer would give a little clarity because it is confusing. That's too big a gaff to be a "continuity error".

**They couldn't POSSIBLY think EVERYONE wouldn't be asking this same question!**

Comment: The script indicates that he's dead. End of. My question is whether the writers decided to ignore or retcon the script in the second film when they recast the actor.

Comment: That script is, as Richard pointed out, pre-production.